# How get replies to channels via the MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, subscription

I am trying to subscribe to the MS Graph API as per their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get replies to messages to chats created in channels. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatmessage) state 'To get change notifications for all messages and replies across channels in a tenant, subscribe to /teams/getAllMessages.'

I recieve notifications for new chats in channels, but not for replies to those chats.

The code is boiler plate as per [ms learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/). The difference is i am subscribing to /chats/getAllMessages and /teams/getAllMessages.

Am i missing a property on the request or something silly?